# Angular Reactive form Error:-ngtsc(-998002)

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

How do I resolve this error?

> Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.ngtsc(-998002)
> I have import ReactiveFormModule in app.module.ts
> and gorm builder and form group in component.ts file.

ts file code:-

```
ngOnInit() {
    // this.fullScreen.isFullscreen=false;

    this.forgotPasswordForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      userid: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    
  }
```

[image]

Comment: And have you also imported FormModule?

Comment: Also add ReactiveFormsModule too

Comment: Remember that you need import the ReactiveFormsModule in the **module where** you declare the component. Think in a module as some independient of your app a cohesive blocks of functionality,. From the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules#angular-modularity): "Imports other modules with the components, directives, and pipes that components in the current module need"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **ReactiveFormsModule** and **FormsModule** to your relevant module imports array.

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```